# semantic_nested_form_for breaks my style

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, formtastic

I'm with Rails 4.0.2, `nested_form`, `formtastic` and bootstrap for the display.

My form is a classic `semantic_form_for` and the generated code was (really simplified of course):

```
<form> 
    <fieldset class="inputs">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div>
                    <label>...</label>
                    <input type="text" />
                </div>
            </div>
            ...
```

I must use nested_form so I change `semantic_form_for` to `semantic_nested_form_for`. Now I have something like that:

```
<form> 
    <fieldset class="inputs">
        <ol>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <li>
                    <label>...</label>
                    <input type="text"> 
                </li>
            </div>
```

And of course my css is really not happy with that...

How can I disable this intrusive ol/li ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found a `semantic_bootstrap_nested_form_for` in the doc. 
It's make for Formtastic and Bootstrap, work nice.